# My video doesn't load in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, microsoft-edge

I am trying to load a video in Internet Explorer. This code works perfectly with Chrome and Firefox, but I get the following error in Microsoft Edge:

> "The specified module could not be found."

Here is my code:

```js
var player = $("<video controls type='video/mp4'></video>");
player.attr("src", video);
```

I also tried this this: `player.get(0).src = video`, but it didn't work.

Can someone explain to me this error?

Comment: Your closing tag is incomplete. It should be `</video>`. Also, what is the value of `video`?

Comment: I close my tag but it doesn't work. The video is a String (relative link with mp4 video)

Comment: Please provide a full, working example, for better assistance. A screenshot of your browser with the developer tools opened would be nice, too. If possible, linking to an online example will help us out immensely. Lastly, please share the version information from Microsoft Edge. You can view this in the [...] menu. You can also provide the version of Windows by running `winver` from the run dialog (WinKey+R).

Comment: I add a screenshot! The version of microsoft edge is 25.10586

Answer (score 0):

Firstly turn on Compatibility View.

Make sure you're not using InPrivate Browsing. InPrivate Browsing might block info or add-ons that a video program needs in order to play properly.

Comment: This should be a comment, as it does not posit a solution to the problem.